# How to make a join using GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I have a node.js app that serves sqlite database data using sequelize via graphql.

The data types are following:

```
Student

id: ID!
name: String!
class: Class


Class

id: ID!
title: String!
floor: Int!
```

I want to get an array of classes with each class containing an array of corresponding students like

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title" : "first",
    "students" : [
      { "id": 1, "name": "John Doe" },
      { "id": 2, "name": "Mary Smith" }
    ]
]
```

Is there any way to do it despite of that kind of reverse linking?

Answer (score 1):

If your database isn't large enough yet, you could always run a one-time script to link it the other way as well, with:

```
Class {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  floor: Int!
  students: [Student]!
}
```

Otherwise, you would have to do a manual query for all students that are taking a certain class and join that data into your query for classes.